# End points of 3D surface being connected

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this set of data, which I would like to plot it in a 3D surface and in a contour by using python (numpy and matplotlib, basically). In this case, I have the X and Y axis as my free coordinates, and the results are described as a dataset on the z-axis.

I've checked many times the data, and it is formatted correctly to my needs.
[Here is a plot of the set in a scatter manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IduM4.png)

The problem is when I try to use the surface plot, where the end points of the (X, Y) mesh are connected, closing the surface and making not visible the part of the image that contains the information I would like to have. [Here is the output I have regarding the surface plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiABK.png) and [here is the output regarding the contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6P7H.png).

The code related to the surface plot (only ploting part) is

```
#...
#X and Y are the coordinates values
#E is the results I am trying to plot

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, E, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.scatter3D(X, Y, E, cmap='Greens')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

Here is the code related to the contour plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contourf(X, Y, E, 10, cmap='RdGy')
ax.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Simplest default with labels')
fig.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/pelednoam/scatter_3d_to_surface

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zVTXpiXyBODhFSsF7qgrlL3hUf7RxRPx . For this data, the first and the second column are the X and Y axis, and the third is the E set.